# Show last fadeIn div on first position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexbox

I have 10 divs which were displayed in a random time.

How can I set the last shown div on top (rank first position) each time and not in the html order of the divs?

Here is my code:

```js
var myVar;    
function showDiv(){
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('.notification').length);
  $('.notification').eq(random).fadeIn(200).delay(3000).fadeOut(200);
  createRandomInterval();
}

function createRandomInterval(){
  setTimeout(showDiv, 500+ Math.random() * 4000);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    createRandomInterval();
});
```

```css
.notification {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  display: none;/* hide initially so that fadIn() fadeOut() will work
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="notification">1</div>
<div class="notification">2</div>
<div class="notification">3</div>
<div class="notification">4</div>
<div class="notification">5</div>
<div class="notification">6</div>
<div class="notification">7</div>
<div class="notification">8</div>
<div class="notification">9</div>
<div class="notification">10</div>
```

Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gkq21ppt/3/

**EDIT: Idea for a solution**

A solution could be, to wrap the divs and set them column-reverse. And then add a JS-code which sets a sequential number as flex order number to every new faded in div.
But I have no idea how to do this, with my low JS skills.

So the loop could look like:

1. create number starting by 1 as variable
2. create class width name e.g. "order-[number]"
3. in ".order-[number]" class set css property "order" to [number]
4. add this class to the loop before it is faded in
5. remove this class after it is faded out

Or?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using [.prependTo()](http://api.jquery.com/prependto/)

What this will do (I think) is remove the active notification and add it back to the container, in the first position. Because of this behaviour, flexbox shouldn't be necessary.

*Note this changes the HTML structure.*

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/sxpwzwng/1/)

```js
var myVar;

function showDiv() {
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('.notification').length);
  $('.notification').eq(random).prependTo('.container').fadeIn(200).delay(3000).fadeOut(200);
  createRandomInterval();
}

function createRandomInterval() {
  setTimeout(showDiv, 500 + Math.random() * 4000);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  createRandomInterval();
});
```

```css
.notification {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  display: none;
  /* hide initially so that fadIn() fadeOut() will work */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="notification">1</div>
  <div class="notification">2</div>
  <div class="notification">3</div>
  <div class="notification">4</div>
  <div class="notification">5</div>
  <div class="notification">6</div>
  <div class="notification">7</div>
  <div class="notification">8</div>
  <div class="notification">9</div>
  <div class="notification">10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: looks right on the first sight. But if div-6 is displayed and div-5 fades in, it will be place not at the top but under div-6 (which is logical regarding the column-reverse property). So it's the same, just the other way around. Every new faded in div should be place at the top, doesn't matter the div-position in html.

Comment: I thought about it again. A solution could be, if you set it column-reverse and add a sequential number as flex order property to every fadedin div. or?

Comment: @RefereeAndy I've updated my answer. I hope it's helpful